# data is not bound when enter key is pressed

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I am using Silverlight & MVVM pattern.

```
<TextBox Name="UserNameText" Text="{Binding Path=Username, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

In this I had bound TextBox to a property Username and when Enter key is pressed and I am executing the LoginCommand in View Model.

```
private void LayoutRoot_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                this._viewModel.LoginCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }
```

When username is entered in TextBox and ENTER key is pressed from the UserName TextBox, the LoginCommand is called, but the value is not updated in propery Username. It still contains null.

The values are bound if only there is a focus lost. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in the Binding. By default, the TextBox only updates it's bound value on `LostFocus`. Setting it to `PropertyChanged` will make it so it updates the bound value anytime the property changes.

```
<TextBox Name="UserNameText" 
         Text="{Binding Path=Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Sorry. It didnt work in Silverlight. Whatever you suggested works in WPF, but not in SL.

Comment: @Jai Here's an example of someone who created an `AttachedProperty` to achieve this behavior in Silverlight: http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-for-silverlight-4-binding/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fix that, it is how binding works (It updates on focus lost, you are right).
However, the solution is pretty simple: you can just to send textbox's text as the command's parameter:

```
this._viewModel.LoginCommand.Execute(((TextBox)sender).Text);
```

Comment: oops. I need to pass both username & password to LoginCommand. How to do that?

Comment: well, you can create combine them in one string like "login|password" and then parse inside command execute delegate) Or you can create an additional entity class like public class UserCreds { string Login {get;set;} string Pass {get;set;} } and pass instance of it into the command. To retrieve Text from Password textbox you should assign a x:Name property to this textbox in xaml and get it through this.nameOfPassTextbox.Text in code-behind